# Plotting a multiple linear regression in R using scatter3D() (package plot3D)

Tags: r, linear-regression, scatter3d, plot3d

I have the following data in a csv file.

```
y,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9
10,2113,1985,38.9,64.7,4,868,59.7,2205,1917
11,2003,2855,38.8,61.3,3,615,55,2096,1575
11,2957,1737,40.1,60,14,914,65.6,1847,2175
13,2285,2905,41.6,45.3,-4,957,61.4,1903,2476
10,2971,1666,39.2,53.8,15,836,66.1,1457,1866
11,2309,2927,39.7,74.1,8,786,61,1848,2339
10,2528,2341,38.1,65.4,12,754,66.1,1564,2092
11,2147,2737,37,78.3,-1,761,58,1821,1909
4,1689,1414,42.1,47.6,-3,714,57,2577,2001
2,2566,1838,42.3,54.2,-1,797,58.9,2476,2254
7,2363,1480,37.3,48,19,984,67.5,1984,2217
```

```r
example = data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,y)
```

How can I graph the variables `x1`, `x2`, `x3` using `scatter3D(x,y,z)`?

I have tried:

```
library("plot3D")
with(example,scatter3D(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3))
```

But I get error:

> Error in min(x,na.rm) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument

Comment: What have you tried and what error message did you get? Have you read the manual page for the function or the vignette for the package?

Comment: yes, but obtain error invalid type of argument

Comment: did you want a regression plane or surface from these 3D data?

Comment: I could try to convert all the data x1, x2, x3 **into an array** `xx = as.array(cbind(x1,x2,x3))`. The graph that I want the:
**plot points**, but **"z"** what value does it take?

Comment: It is 3d not 4d. Try `with(example, scatter3D(y, x1, x2))`.

Comment: If you have 3 series of points the only option would be to predict one of them in terms of the other two. Plotting y on the basis of x1,x2,x3 would take 4 dimensions. You could conceivably plot y on the basis of two of those holding the third one constant. ( deleted my earlier comment about plot3D not plotting regression fits. It can but the fit argument is given to the `surf` argument.)

Comment: if it works, rather if I have many values such as **x1, x2, y, x3, x4** and I want to graph them. Could this library be used?

Comment: Your last question is not clear regarding what is meant by "graph them". What is clear is that no function would be able to make a 5 dimensional plot.

Comment: ok I understand, I was asking to create multiple graphs with the variables and of course I also want to know how good they would be adding style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to plot a regression plane. The `scatter3d` function in package `car` will do that. You need to install `car` and `rgl`. First let's make your data more accessible:

```
dput(example)
structure(list(y = c(10L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 
4L, 2L, 7L), x1 = c(2113L, 2003L, 2957L, 2285L, 2971L, 2309L, 
2528L, 2147L, 1689L, 2566L, 2363L), x2 = c(1985L, 2855L, 1737L, 
2905L, 1666L, 2927L, 2341L, 2737L, 1414L, 1838L, 1480L), x3 = c(38.9, 
38.8, 40.1, 41.6, 39.2, 39.7, 38.1, 37, 42.1, 42.3, 37.3), x4 = c(64.7, 
61.3, 60, 45.3, 53.8, 74.1, 65.4, 78.3, 47.6, 54.2, 48), x5 = c(4L, 
3L, 14L, -4L, 15L, 8L, 12L, -1L, -3L, -1L, 19L), x6 = c(868L, 
615L, 914L, 957L, 836L, 786L, 754L, 761L, 714L, 797L, 984L), 
    x7 = c(59.7, 55, 65.6, 61.4, 66.1, 61, 66.1, 58, 57, 58.9, 
    67.5), x8 = c(2205L, 2096L, 1847L, 1903L, 1457L, 1848L, 1564L, 
    1821L, 2577L, 2476L, 1984L), x9 = c(1917L, 1575L, 2175L, 
    2476L, 1866L, 2339L, 2092L, 1909L, 2001L, 2254L, 2217L)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

install.packages("car")
install.packages("rgl")
library(car)
library(rgl)
scatter3d(y~x1+x2, example)
```

The plot window will be small. Use the mouse to drag the lower right corner to make it bigger. You can drag within the plot to rotate it.

[image: 3d plot]

Comment: Upvoted for the excellence of the answer and the coolness of the 3D plot.

Comment: Can I use this library? **`library("plot3D")`**,or it's necessary to use these :`library(car)
library(rgl)`

Comment: Read the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plot3D/vignettes/plot3D.pdf) for **package** (not library) `plot3D`. It seems to have many functions, but I didn't see examples plotting a regression plane. You haven't told us anything about what you are trying to do except that you want to do 3d plots. Earlier I suggested `with(example, scatter3D(y, x1, x2))`. Did that not work? If not, why?

Comment: excuse me, it's **`library("plot3Drgl")`**.My goal was to try to create an elegant graphic but have the function **add = TRUE**